# Can D-brane vibrate and generate more allowed boundary conditions?

Tags: string-theory, conformal-field-theory, boundary-conditions, branes

Previously the D-branes were said to be fixed hyperplane or a boundary where a string could end. The commonly known boundary conditions were Dirichlet Brane and the Neumann Brane and the superposition of them.

But recently, the view was that the notion of D-brane were more general, and the string was a $D_0$ Brane. This led to the think that can the D-brane vibrate? just like that of the string? For example, the normal component of the string that ended on the Neumann Brane vanished, but if the Neumann D brane itself were allowed to vibrate, then the string which does not have a normal component with respect to the Neumann D brane would have a none zero normal component in the target space because of the vibration of the D brane.

Can D-brane vibrate and generate more allowed boundary conditions?